# Integral representation of the nth power of the zeroth Bessel function?

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

Zeroth Bessel function has the following integral representation:
$$
J_0 (x) = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dz}{\pi} e^{ix\cos z}
$$

Does the nth power of the zeroth Bessel function $J_0 (x)^n$ also have similar integral representation ($n \in N$)? I would like to find the integral representation  of  $J_0 (x)^n$ in the simplest form possible (It would be nice if it involved only a single integral), but it is also fine if the obtained expressions are a little more complicated.

Comment: Perhaps start here:  https://www.amazon.com/Treatise-Functions-Cambridge-Mathematical-Library/dp/0521483913

Comment: @mjw Thank you. I will look it up.

Comment: For the square we have, for example, $$
J_0^2 (x) = \frac{2}{\pi }\int_0^{\pi /2} {J_0 (2x\cos t)dt} .
$$